# Select by href starting by a string

Tags: java, selenium, select, href

I'm looking for a solution of my problem.
I want to find all the href elements of my web page starting by

```
href="/lite/..... "
```

I want to check the http status of all my href starting by /lite/
My test is in Java and I'm using selenium

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use XPath? Then you could use something like:

`//*[starts-with(@href,'/lite')]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS selector:

```
elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[href^='/lite/']"));
```

Note that it doesn't return the links for a frame element.

Comment: Working to, but the over solution is more adapted in my case. Thanks !